# Rails_admin geocoder using google maps

Tags: google-maps, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-geocoder

Hi i am currently doing a project but they need a google map in the rails_admin to be able to do the geocoder so that they can use the google map straight and not just get the location's coordinates before they can do it.

i have checked this out https://github.com/beyondthestory/rails_admin_map_field but the problem is that i get this error

```
Fetching git://github.com/jasonl/rails_admin_map_field.git
fatal: remote error: 
  Repository not found.
Retrying git clone 'git://github.com/jasonl/rails_admin_map_field.git' "/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/rails_admin_map_field-b98ef0a93697bab8818013f8738b246fe83822a9" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/jasonl/rails_admin_map_field.git' "/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/rails_admin_map_field-b98ef0a93697bab8818013f8738b246fe83822a9" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/simplybel/gamification/rigpirateprivate has failed.
fatal: remote error: 
  Repository not found.
Retrying git clone 'git://github.com/jasonl/rails_admin_map_field.git' "/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/rails_admin_map_field-b98ef0a93697bab8818013f8738b246fe83822a9" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (3/3): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/jasonl/rails_admin_map_field.git' "/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/rails_admin_map_field-b98ef0a93697bab8818013f8738b246fe83822a9" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/simplybel/gamification/rigpirateprivate has failed.
fatal: remote error: 
  Repository not found.
Git error: command `git clone
```

'git://github.com/jasonl/rails_admin_map_field.git'
"/home/simplybel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/rails_admin_map_field-b98ef0a93697bab8818013f8738b246fe83822a9"
--bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory
/home/simplybel/gamification/rigpirateprivate has failed.

now i dont know what to do or how to make it work any help will be of great help! using rails 4.2 , devise and the geocoder

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to [embed google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) using an iframe in `show`, `list` view of `model`:

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

You need to set [pretty_value](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#output-formatting) for the field which renders the map with the `iframe` content as mentioned in the code block above.

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model 'Shop' do
    show do
      field :location do
        pretty_value do
          iframe_content(value).html_safe
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Here `iframe_content` renders the `iframe` which google maps requires you to put on your page. It is required to call `html_safe` so that rails understands that this html content is sanitized and will not cause any security risk, otherwise it will interpret it as plain string.

`iframe_content` has to be a method defined inside `Shop` model.

You might have to make some changes to this solution, it might not work right out of the box. Hope this helps.